# SSH from windows to linux returns no android devices

Tags: android, ssh, server, adb

This is my first post here, so please bear with me.

I have 2 machines - 1 local (windows), 1 remote (linux, different network). The local one has android devices connected to it. I'm trying to create an adb server on my local, ssh to the linux and  get the local device listed on the remote, so I can run commands on it from the remote (where my Java project resides). The idea behind is so that anyone who connects to the linux should be able to run commands on the aggregated list of devices (multiple users connected = multiple devices).

I get the

```
adb: failed to check server version: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Success
```

when I try to run the 'adb devices' command from linux - so the connection is there, but not working properly, and i no longer have any idea what else to try.

What I do is run the

```
adb start-server
```

command, after which I run the

```
ssh -XC -R 5037:localhost:5037 user@ip
```

command and then the

```
adb devices
```

command through the ssh connection.

Creating a SSH connection from a linux to a linux, both using the same adb version (33.0.3) works, the issue appears when doing this from windows to linux.

I seem to have tried everything from firewalls, to udevrules, SELinux restrictions, to using the same adb versions (33.0.3), to driver / os updates, to using a different port to start the server on... nothing seems to work for me.

Perhaps my understanding of how the adb server & client work is wrong - in which case please help me understand the proper way to use it.

What else can I try and what other options do I have to achieve the same result (if any) ?